# System.ExecutionEngineException using especific .dll (CodeArtEng.Gauge.dll)

Tags: c#

I'm using this lib (*CodeArtEng.Gauge.dll*) and i cant run my application because they cause an error on "InitializeComponent()" and i don't know why.

I ask some support with the developer but they don't know why this append.

Any one use it or can help me with this.

Many thanks.

[App and Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgHnE.png)

[Exception Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7ALI.png)

Comment: `System.ExecutionEngineException` means that the runtime has detected a serious problem. This is typically caused by a library that overwrites memory it doesn't own or corrupts the stack. It seems that the library you're using is having a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened in Version 1.0.0. The issue was due to the security settings of this library. The problem had been resolved in released version 1.0.1